# Unable to paste special from clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to complete a code which requires me to paste data from a Ctrl+A/C'd webpage into a sheet. This is what I've done so far.

```
Sub testPaste()

Sheets("sheet2").Delete
Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wscel As Range
Set wscel = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1")

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

strPaste = DataObj.GetText

wscel.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

The code however gives me an error 1004. Removing `(xlPasteValues)` fixes it but it pastes the data as is which I can't work with. what is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the brackets `wscel.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` should be `wscel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @Tom In this case - a single `ByVal` argument - VBA doesn't distinguish between having or omitting the brackets.  If you were using a `ByRef` argument or two arguments of any type, such as `wscel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True` then, yes, you would get an error from `wscel.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Range.PasteSpecial`, which applies to pasting **Excel Formatted Range Objects** - documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial).  Unfortunately, what sits on your Clipboard *isn't* an Excel Range Object, so you need [the `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.Worksheet.pastespecial) instead.

If your clipboard contains, for example an HTML sample, then you can "Paste As Text" like so:

```
    wscel.Worksheet.Activate
    wscel.Activate
    wscel.Worksheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= False
```

And, yes - this is one of the few cases were you can't [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Good catch. Of course I noticed the extraneous parentheses, and totally missed the copy/paste from webpage. Upvoted.